# Ror Gem to point out location on google map by clicking on link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, rubygems, google-maps-markers

I would like to ask which is the best solution for integrating google maps into ruby on rails apps so that on clicking on location link it will redirect me to google maps page and points to that location. Is a specific gem worth it?

Thanks for positive inputs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [gmaps4rails](http://rubygems.org/gems/gmaps4rails).

For other potential options:

- Check out the [Geocoding & Maps](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/geocoding___maps) section at [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com)
- Search [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org) for "[maps](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=maps)"
- Search google for "[google maps rails gem](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+maps+rails+gem)"